# Most efficient way to convert rails query result to tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm fairly new to ruby/rails.  I have an AR query that joins 2 tables in postgres- mutations and effects.  Mutations has many Effects. 
The result of that query gives something like:

```
mutation_id  |  chr  | pos |  gene  |  eff_impact | eff_transcript
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1            |  1    | 123 | JAK   |  bad         | tx123
1            |  1    | 123 | JAK   |  worse       | tx456
2            |  4    | 456 | KRAS  |  fine        | tx234
2            |  4    | 456 | KRAS  |  scary       | tx483
3            |  7    | 789 | SMURF |  helpful     | tx987
```

This gives me a flat result set with duplicate values from the mutations table, since a mutation has many effects.

What I ultimately need is an array of hashes with a tree structure as follows:

```
[
{"mutation_id" => 1, 
 "chr" => 1, 
 "pos" => 123, 
 "gene" => "JAK", 
 "effects" => [
  {"eff_impact" => "bad", "eff_transcript" => "tx123"},
  {"eff_impact" => "worse", "eff_transcript" => "tx456"},
 ]
},
{"mutation_id" => 2, 
 "chr" => 4, 
 "pos" => 546, 
 "gene" => "KRAS", 
 "effects" => [
  {"eff_impact" => "fine", "eff_transcript" => "tx234"},
  {"eff_impact" => "scary", "eff_transcript" => "tx483"},
 ]
},
{"mutation_id" => 3, 
 "chr" => 7, 
 "pos" => 546, 
 "gene" => "SMURF", 
 "effects" => [
  {"eff_impact" => "helpful", "eff_transcript" => "tx987"}
 ]
}
]
```

The result is ~ 100k rows. I'd prefer to have the initial query return the AR result with this tree structure, if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Try `Mutation.your_existing_query_here.group_by{|e| e.mutation_id}`. You should end up with a hash where the keys are the mutation_id and the values are an array of elements.  You might vary the group_by block to suit your needs.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom yes I was able to get that far, but wasn't sure about the varying to suit part.  I did some experimentation and couldn't quite wrap my head around how to use multiple keys in group_by

Comment: `.group_by{|e| [e.mutation_id, e.chr]}` would group by the unique combination of those two fields.